# For loop working in C#

Tags: c#

I am writing a program that finds the number of 1's in an array.. but the "scanning" inside the "for" loop takes place only once.

```
for (i = 0; i < 11; i++ )
{
    k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
    if (k==1)
    {
        ans++;
    }
    //   Console.WriteLine("i == {0}", i);
}
```

Is this normal in C# or am I doing something wrong? I tried to search for this problem but cannot find any answers!

Comment: its unclear what you are trying to solve, I don't see any array there for you to count 1's in it, you seem to be reading the users input 11 times and then counting how many times they enter the number 1

Comment: what is your result you are expecting?

Comment: This is perfectly valid C#-code and should work, at least if you are to get the number of 1s the user put in.

Comment: You should consider to use int.TryParse() though, because Console.Read() could contain anything but a number

Comment: where is array? also i think you should use ReadLine instead of Read.

Comment: As an aside, I don't think [`Console.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx) does what you think it does.  For example, if you type `1` and hit enter, it will return `49`, `13` and `10` - the character codes for `1\r\n`.  There's also no need to convert it to `int` as that it's return type.  You probably want `ReadLine`, though it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Sayse even though question mentions Array... I thought of just scanning user input and counting number of 1's in it.. it should give the same result right?? and i mentioned 11 just as example.

Comment: @Mivaweb Number of 1's ie, 'ans' as output..sry i hadn't mentioned it.

Comment: @HimBromBeere No, the code is not working properly for number of 1's in user input..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
Console.ReadLine()
```

instead of

```
Console.Read()
```

When you reach the first Console.Read() the inputstream is saved but only the first character is returned by the Read method. Subsequent calls to the Read method retrieve your input one character at a time from the inputstream.

Ex:
First iteration:

```
k = Console.Read(); //you input "abc1", k = a
```

Second iteration:

```
k = Console.Read(); // k = b
```

and so on.
When the last character in the inputstream is returned, the next call to Console.Read() will display the console again so you can input a new string and hit Enter.

[Console.Read() docu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes it worked .. can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

There's no array in your code, actually. Personally I'd rewrite this to:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
for (i = 0; i < input.Length; i++ )
{
    int k = Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(i, 1));
    if (k==1)
    {
        ans++;
    }
}
```

Which lets the user enter a string first and then does all the parsing. Of course, the user may enter more or less than exactly 11 characters in this code, so if you really need 11 numbers, I'd add extra messages and checks.

Also this code (as your original code) fail miserably if the user enters something non-numeric, so exception handling would be on the task list as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code, I think it will answer your problem

```
 string[] sample = { "1", "1", "3" };

        var a = (from w in sample
                 where w == "1"
                 select w).ToList();

        Console.Write(a.Count);
```